# Connection failed: Access denied for user 'i366059'@'192.168.XX.XX' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to register a user to my database in phpMyAdmin, but when i enter the details for him i get the message "Connection failed: Access denied for user 'i366059'@'192.168.XX.XX' (using password: YES)"

I have created the database in phpMyAdmin, with the fields required to save the information. I have a few folders with php code that send it to the database.

this is my register php:

```
    <?php

    $activeHome="";
    $activeCourse = "";
    $activeVisit = "";
    $activeContact = 'active';
    $content = '<div style="height: 1100px" id="content">
                    <a href="index.php"><img id="topPicture" src="img/header.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Please enter your information to create a new account</p>
                    <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
                      <br>First name<br>
                      <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First name">
                      <br>Last name<br>
                      <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last name">
                      <br>User name<br>
                      <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="User name">
                      <br>Password<br>
                      <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Choose a password"><br><br>
                      <button type="submit">Sign up now</button>
                    </form>
                </div>';
include 'template.php';
```

my signup php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user1 (first_name, last_name, uid, pwd)
VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$uid', '$pwd')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

header("Location: registered.php");
```

and my dbh.php: // where my information for database is

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("studmysql01.fhict.local","i366XXX","rus876XXXX","dbi366XXX");

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: double/triple check your credentials

Comment: Exactly what does this have to do with `html` or `javascript`? Please don't spam tags just to get attention.

Comment: I would also guess that the credentials are wrong.

Just a tipp: 
Always prepare your statements, otherwise some can do SQL Injection ;)